# Cannot enter safe mode or set mysql root password new install ubuntu 18

Tags: mysql

I have tried reinstalling nothing seemes to help

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 8688
$ 2018-09-04T20:51:49.362162Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2018-09-04T20:51:49.365443Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-09-04T20:51:49.367974Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
2018-09-04T20:52:07.496620Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2018-09-04T20:52:07.499628Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2018-09-04T20:52:07.502089Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Results of `dpkg -L mysql-server`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server/copyright  
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server/changelog.Debian.gz


jbarton@jbarton-Latitude-E7470:~/Code/signlab$ systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-09-04 15:14:31 MDT; 20min ago
  Process: 9888 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid- 
   file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9879 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9890 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 28 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─9890 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid- 
   file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Sep 04 15:14:30 jbarton-Latitude-E7470 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL 
Community Server...
Sep 04 15:14:31 jbarton-Latitude-E7470 systemd[1]: Started MySQL 
Community Server.
```

Comment: If you data is or was backed up tried purging then reinstall again run `sudo apt purge mysql`

Comment: tried following this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset but get jbarton@jbarton-Latitude-E7470:~$    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
jbarton@jbarton-Latitude-E7470:~$    sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
[1] 9722
jbarton@jbarton-Latitude-E7470:~$    mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

Comment: have tried to purge and reinstall still did not help

Comment: Can you connect with `sudo mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: I don't knnow the password new install

Comment: tried this here but did not work https://superuser.com/questions/56743/mysql-wont-start

Comment: This is a new ubuntu 18 install with a new mysql-server install never prompted for password and not letting me manually set one or enter safemode

Comment: Please run `dpkg -L mysql-server` and add to your question

Comment: ran dpkg -L mysql-server

Comment: What does `systemctl status mysql` say

Comment: updated systemctl status mysql

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was that after opening safe mode I was not going to a new terminal tab and the process was running in the background, after opening a new tab I was able to enter safemode and update the password,

Comment: Glad it worked out!